# Primefaces Calendar not popping up

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Edit - please see bottom.
I've got a primefaces calendar component on my page. The textbox appears but when I click it the calendar does not appear. Here is the component code.

```
  <p:calendar id="clientApptTime"  value="#{ScheduleMB.datePrime}"  
            pattern="HH:mm" timeOnly="true"  />
```

My facelet and the template both use h:head and h:body tags and I have the
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" up top.

I'm using primefaces 3.3.1, java 1.6 and Mojarra 2.1.
Also I'm not getting any error messages on either the server or my error console.

Anybody have any ideas?

And here is the rendered page source:

```
   span id="j_idt34:clientApptTime"><input id="j_idt34:clientApptTime_input"
   name="j_idt34:clientApptTime_input" type="text" class="ui-inputfield ui-widget
   ui-state-default ui-corner-all" /></span><script id="j_idt34:clientApptTime_s"
   type="text/javascript">$(function()
  {PrimeFaces.cw('Calendar','widget_j_idt34_clientApptTime',
  {id:'j_idt34:clientApptTime',popup:true,locale:'en_US',dateFormat:'m/d/y
                                               hh:mm',timeOnly:true,stepHour:1,stepMinute:1,stepSecond:1,hourMin:0,hourMax:23,minuteMin:0,
  minuteMax:59,secondMin:0,secondMax:59});});</script>
```

Comment: try `value="#{scheduleMB.datePrime}"` instead (not capital S)

Comment: does any other primefaces component works for you ? is it inside form? (no nested form ?) did you placed your primefaces jar in the lib folder?

Comment: This is my only primefaces component so far. It is inside a form and there is a primefaces jar in my lib folder. There is also a tomahawk component on the page and I wonder if that is interfering.

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I verified. I have them in both my facelet and the template.

Comment: can you post the rendered html?

Comment: Test it in a minimal view. E.g. `<h:body><h:form><p:calendar pattern="HH:mm" timeOnly="true" /></h:form></h:body>`.

Comment: Okay, seems Primefaces does NOT play with Tomahawk. I removed all the Tomahawk references and then the Primefaces calendar worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer seems to be that Primefaces will not work with Tomahawk. After I removed all the Tomahawk references Primefaces worked fine. Anyone know what I can do about that (this may be a question for another post)?