# PrimeFaces calendar won't popup when used together with Tomahawk components

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, tomahawk

I have an application with a couple of Tomahawk components that I'd like to add a PrimeFaces calendar to. However, the PrimeFaces calendar won't popup unless I remove all the Tomahawk components. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Edit- Here is part of the code I was talking about. I like the primefaces calendar time selector and want to use it, the tomahawk version is too clumsy. If I remove the tomahawk component the p:calendar works fine, but does not render when any tomahawk components are in my .xhtml (I use a tomahawk scheduler also that I didn't include here).

```
    <h:outputLabel>Enter Appt Date:Time</h:outputLabel>

<t:inputDate popupCalendar="true" type="both" value="#{ScheduleMB.from}"/>

<p:calendar id="clientApptTime"  value="#{ScheduleMB.datePrime}"  
    pattern="HH:mm" timeOnly="true" mode="popup"     /> 

<h:outputLabel>Enter Appt. Length</h:outputLabel>

<h:selectOneMenu id="apptDuration" value="#{ScheduleMB.apptTime}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="45" itemLabel="45 minutes"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="60" itemLabel="60 minutes"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="90" itemLabel="90 minutes"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="120" itemLabel="120 minutes"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Please add the dom tree concerning the calendar to your post. Besides that, what do you mean by "add" to a calendar? As far i know the calendar is not meant to contain child components. I suspect that youll have to write your own Render to achieve such behaviour.

Comment: Please add relevant pieces of code. (Not the whole page, create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @Dave do u see any errors in browser console?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Primefaces Calendar not popping up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374904/primefaces-calendar-not-popping-up)